# How to Select a checbox by its corresponding label name

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

I am relatively new to xpath and I'm having an issue with Selecting a checkbox.

The following expression works fine

```
:xpath=//div/label[@for='chkCat2']
```

But I need to select a checkbox based on its  label name (**Music** in this case)

Unfortunately, this -

```
xpath=.//div[label[contains(text(),'Music')]
```

is clicking on the label, not on the checkbox.

How is it possible to do that? I also tried this one but its not able to locate the element:

```
xpath=.//div[label[contains(text(),'Music')]/preceding-sibling::label]
```

That's the sample of the code:

```
<input name="ctl00$cphContent$ThreeMedia$categoriesRepeater$ctl01$ctl00" 
data-bind="attr:{'id': 'chkCat' + id, 'data-id': id}, checked: selected"  id="chkCat2" data-id="2" type="checkbox">
<label data-bind="attr:{'for': 'chkCat' + id}" for="chkCat2" class=" firepath-matching-node"></label>
<label class="chkbox-content margin-bottom-0" data-bind="text: name">Music</label>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I need to select a checkbox based on its label name (Music in this case)

Assuming `div` is the parent element of the provided `checkbox` element, try using below `xpath` :-

```
.//div[normalize-space(.)='Music']/input
```

or more specific

```
.//div[normalize-space(.)='Music']/input[@type='checkbox']
```

one more

```
.//div[label[text() = 'Music']]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below mentioned `xpath`

```
//label[text()= 'Music']/..//preceding-sibling::input[@id='chkCat2']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<label>` tag and move ahead with `<input>` tag using `preceding-sibling keyword`.

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`